# Controlling SNS policy through cloud formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns, serverless

I am trying to invoke lambda function in different account through SNS. SNS topic will invoke lambda functions in different aws accounts (1:N). It is similar to steps described [in](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sns-create-x-account-permissions.html).

I am trying to achieve these steps through cloudformation but am not able to find a way to achieve step number 3, i.e add permission to subscribe to topic through cloudformation.

```
aws sns add-permission \
--region us-east-1 \
--topic-arn Amazon SNS topic arn \
--label lambda-access \
--aws-account-id B \
--action-name Subscribe ListSubscriptionsByTopic Receive
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would look something like this:

```
 TopicLambdaPermission:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
  Properties:
    FunctionName: {"Ref": LambdaFunctionArn }
    Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
    Principal: 'sns.amazonaws.com'
    SourceArn: {"Ref": TopicArn }
```